# RabbitMQ for sending bulk emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have been looking at whether I can use RabbitMQ to assist in sending bulk emails from a console application (C# ASP.NET CORE).

I have had a good look through their website but can not find a specific tutorial on the use of RabbitMQ for bulk emailing.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Are you intending to distribute the task between components that actually send the email? i.e. does the console app just trigger the process in a wider system? That might make sense to use a reliable queue, yes. Else what are you hoping to gain using RabbitMQ - restart and resume, reliability, something else? I'm not sure you'll find a specific "Here's how to use Rabbit for emailing" sample.

Comment: I think perhaps you're coming at this from a slightly odd angle.  You'd usually use Rabbit to add resilience/robustness to your application - so if your application crashes or goes offline, then requests "to do things" (e.g. send emails) are not lost, and the application is able to pick-up where it left off when it comes back online.

It would not be unreasonable to have a part of your application putting messages (requests to send an email) on a queue, and another part of the application pulling those messages off the queue - classic producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: It could be useful if you want to have a central emailing component that can be used from other components in your system.

I actually think that you saw the Work Queues image of the getting started page and thought that you could magically send the emails from your producer through a queue to your email consumers and I think this is not really possible or useful since the clients would have to run code in order to register themselves at the exchange/queue

Comment: Incidentally, the Rabbit "getting started" C# tutorial is _really good_.  https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

You should read it thoroughly for a better understanding of what Rabbit will and won't bring to the table.

Comment: I've a foreach loop for users that generates body for emails & I was asked to look at whether I might use a bulk emailer & quoted RabbitMQ. From what I've read on their site & comments here it would seem the only sensible implementation might be to use the producer with my loop, then write a consumer that will send the emails and in the case of an application failure this would allow the messages to continue - but this wouldn't give me reports on whether the emails themselves have delivered/failed - nor would it provide robustness for the emailing part (inside the consumer) of the application.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I've read on their site & comments here it would seem the only sensible implementation might be to use the producer with my loop, then write a consumer that will send the emails and in the case of an application failure this would allow the messages to continue - but this wouldn't give me reports on whether the emails themselves have delivered/failed - nor would it provide robustness for the emailing part (inside the consumer) of the application

This is reasonable enough and yes, you will have to implement parts of this system yourself, and test it to ensure reliability meets your expectations. You should read about these RabbitMQ topics:

- Durability
- Persistence
- Message acknowledgements
- Publisher confirms.

You may also be interested in [this plugin](https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-email).

And finally, please only send email to people who want to receive it, and give people an unsubscribe option.

Comment: At first blush, it sounds like three components.  1) Email Requester (Producer); 2) Consumer sending emails; 3) Listener watching for email rejections.  #2 & 3 both do database updates by email address for status/history/audit.  #1 & 2 utilize the MQ

Comment: Now you mention a "loop" for generating email requests.  Is this a batch process started at user request?  A response to a user click on a website?  Is processing time comparatively large?  Important considerations to the approach chosen.